# Flask Operational Error for no such table

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I made this todo program as a practice I have been experiencing this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: todo
[SQL: SELECT todo.id AS todo_id, todo.name AS todo_name
FROM todo]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

Here is my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///todo.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Todo(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(length=100), nullable=False, unique=True)

def add_todo(_todo):
    with app.app_context():
        db.session.add(_todo)
    with app.app_context():
        db.session.commit()

@app.route('/read-form', methods=["POST"])
def read_form():
    todo_name = request.form["todo-name"]
    todo = Todo(name=todo_name)
    add_todo(todo)
    return redirect(url_for('main_page'))

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def main_page():
    todo_list = Todo.query.all()
    return render_template('main.html', Todos=todo_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The error happens in the Todo.query.all() line

I have tried using app.app_context()

Comment: Have you actually created the tables? Your code doesn't

Comment: does there have to be? the html code ignores it in that case

Comment: There is no HTML in your code and how do you think you'll write to a database that doesn't exist exactly? The error is telling you it doesn't exist.

Comment: Does the database file `/todo.db` exist?  And do the tables already exist in that database?

Answer (score 0):

check if the database file todo.db exists in the same directory as your script. If not, ensure Flask has the necessary permissions to create it.

If you haven't already, initialize your database and create the necessary tables. You can do this by running the following commands in your terminal.

```
flask db init
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

Comment: which terminal do you mean both python and normal cmd says no such command db

Comment: Now it says there is already a sqlalchemy instance

Comment: then run your code it should work

Comment: No it doesnt same error